# List item going bottom

Tags: html, css

I got 3 divs displayed in inline-block way. Each of them has a simple list with links. The thing is second list has only one item.

The way it looks:

[image]

The way it should look:

[image]

Thanks for any advice!

```
.column_links{
    display: inline-block;
    width:28%;
    margin-right:60px;
}
.column_social{
    width:29%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right:60px;
}
.column_new{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: not a duplicate rofl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use need to set `vertical-align:top` for `display:inline-block`.

Because default value is `vertical-align:baseline`. So, that your div goes to the bottom.

```
.column_new,
.column_social,
.column_new{
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

Here is [Demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/pw4zd2tL/)

Answer (score 0):

use **vertical-align:top**

Try this [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2kwez3kx/)

```
.column_new,
.column_social,
.column_new{
   vertical-align: top;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for repsonse!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.column_links {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 28%;
  margin-right: 60px;
}
.column_social {
  width: 29%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 60px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.column_new {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="column_links">
  <h3>
LINKS
</h3>
  <hr>
  <ul>
    <li>list 1</li>
    <li>list 2</li>
    <li>list 3</li>
    <li>list 4</li>
    <li>list 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="column_social">
  <h3>
FIND ME
</h3>
  <hr>
  <ul>
    <li>list 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="column_new">
  <h3>
NEW
</h3>
  <hr>
  <ul>
    <li>list 1</li>
    <li>list 2</li>
    <li>list 3</li>
    <li>list 4</li>
    <li>list 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

here is jsfiddle: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2kwez3kx/3/)